# Get function's title from documentation

Tags: r, documentation

I would like to get the title of a base function (e.g.: `rnorm`) in one of my scripts. That is included in the documentation, but I have no idea how to "grab" it.

I mean the line given in the *RD* files as `\title{}` or the top line in documentation.

Is there any simple way to do this **without** calling `Rd_db` function from `tools` and parse all RD files -- as having a very big overhead for this simple stuff? Other thing: I tried with `parse_Rd` too, but:

- I do not know which *Rd* file holds my function,
- I have no *Rd* files on my system (just *rdb*, *rdx* and *rds*).

So a function to parse the (offline) documentation would be the best :)

---

POC demo:

```
> get.title("rnorm")
[1] "The Normal Distribution"
```

Comment: `fgui:::parseHelp("rnorm")` is supposed to do that but it seems its out of date.  Go through its source and revise it to use the latest version of the tools package and R or contact the authors to see if they have already done that.

Comment: Thank you @G.Grothendieck for pointing my attention to that function, I tried to update it to work with current R system, but DWin was faster :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at the code for `help,` you see that the function `index.search` seems to be what is pulling in the location of the help files, and that the default for the associated find.packages() function is NULL. Turns out tha tthere is neither a help fo that function nor is exposed, so I tested the usual suspects for which package it was in (base, tools, utils), and ended up with "utils:

```
utils:::index.search("+", find.package())
#[1] "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/library/base/help/Arithmetic"
```

So:

```
 ghelp <- utils:::index.search("+", find.package())
 gsub("^.+/", "", ghelp)
#[1] "Arithmetic"
ghelp <- utils:::index.search("rnorm", find.package())
gsub("^.+/", "", ghelp)
#[1] "Normal"
```

What you are asking for is `\title{Title}`, but here I have shown you how to find the specific Rd file to parse and is sounds as though you already know how to do that.

EDIT: @Hadley has provided a method for getting all of the help text, once you know the package name, so applying that to the index.search() value above:

```
target <- gsub("^.+/library/(.+)/help.+$", "\\1", utils:::index.search("rnorm", 
                                                                  find.package()))
doc.txt <- pkg_topic(target, "rnorm")  # assuming both of Hadley's functions are here
print(doc.txt[[1]][[1]][1])
#[1] "The Normal Distribution"
```

Comment: Except those aren't really files - they're actually somewhat opaque pointers to objects stored inside r object databases.

Comment: @hadley : You took further steps, but we needed to also extract the package name, and then extract the first line from the pkg_topic value as illustrated above to complete the task.

Comment: I thought he knew the package: base. Anyway the question is confusing. Hard to know what's actually needed.

Comment: Also you can't really assume that the title wi always be in that position.  But I see that I could be using index.search. Nice find!

Answer (score 4):

It's not completely obvious what you want, but the code below will get the Rd data structure corresponding to the the topic you're interested in - you can then manipulate that to extract whatever you want.

There may be simpler ways, but unfortunately very little of the needed coded is exported and documented.  I really wish there was a base `help` package.

```
pkg_topic <- function(package, topic, file = NULL) {
  # Find "file" name given topic name/alias
  if (is.null(file)) {
    topics <- pkg_topics_index(package)
    topic_page <- subset(topics, alias == topic, select = file)$file

    if(length(topic_page) < 1)
      topic_page <- subset(topics, file == topic, select = file)$file

    stopifnot(length(topic_page) >= 1)
    file <- topic_page[1]    
  }

  rdb_path <- file.path(system.file("help", package = package), package)
  tools:::fetchRdDB(rdb_path, file)
}

pkg_topics_index <- function(package) {
  help_path <- system.file("help", package = package)

  file_path <- file.path(help_path, "AnIndex")
  if (length(readLines(file_path, n = 1)) < 1) {
    return(NULL)
  }

  topics <- read.table(file_path, sep = "\t", 
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE, comment.char = "", quote = "", header = FALSE)

  names(topics) <- c("alias", "file") 
  topics[complete.cases(topics), ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you @hadley too for this nice set of code and also helping to get a nice answer.