# R functions help into a quarto document

Tags: r, knitr, documentation, quarto

The following code gives the examples [r](/questions/tagged/r) codes along their output for first six topics from [stats](/questions/tagged/stats) [r](/questions/tagged/r) library.

````
---
title: "Help"
format: pdf
---

```{r}
#| echo: false
#| class-output: r
library(purrr)
map(
      .x             = ls("package:stats", all = FALSE)[1:6] 
    , .f             = example
    , package        = "stats"
    , character.only = TRUE
    , type           = "html"
    )
```
````

[image]

I want to tweak this output a little bit.

**Expected Output**

Wondering how to add each topic title as a section and then its corresponding code and output.

**Edited**

The `helpExtract` from `SOfun` [r](/questions/tagged/r) package can be used to extract specified portions of [r](/questions/tagged/r) help files for use in [sweave](/questions/tagged/sweave) or [r-markdown](/questions/tagged/r-markdown) documents.

```
remotes::install_github("mrdwab/SOfun")

library(SOfun)

helpExtract(
    Function = acf
  , section  = c("Description", "Usage", "Arguments", "Details", "Value", "Examples")[1] 
  , type     = c("m_code", "m_text", "s_code", "s_text")[2]
  )
```

However, can't figured out how to use this function to extract topic title.

**Edited (2023-04-19)**

@Julian's solution is effective for the [stats](/questions/tagged/stats) [r](/questions/tagged/r) package, but it does not function properly with the [meta](/questions/tagged/meta) [r](/questions/tagged/r) package. When attempting to use it with the [meta](/questions/tagged/meta) [r](/questions/tagged/r) package, the following error is generated:

> Error in purrr::map():i In index: 1.Caused by error in file():! cannot
> open the connectionError in vctrs_vec_compat(.y, .purrr_user_env):
> object 'topic_title' not foundError in cat(res, sep = "\n"): object
> 'res' not found1

Comment: Yes, topic title as section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want? I added a toc to see whether the chapters are as intended (code idea comes from [here](https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/issues/2370) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8379570/get-functions-title-from-documentation)):

````
---
title: "Help"
format: pdf
toc: true
number-sections: true
---


```{r}
#| echo: false

# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8379570/get-functions-title-from-documentation
pkg_topic <- function(package, topic, file = NULL) {
  # Find "file" name given topic name/alias
  if (is.null(file)) {
    topics <- pkg_topics_index(package)
    topic_page <- subset(topics, alias == topic, select = file)$file

    if(length(topic_page) < 1)
      topic_page <- subset(topics, file == topic, select = file)$file

    stopifnot(length(topic_page) >= 1)
    file <- topic_page[1]    
  }

  rdb_path <- file.path(system.file("help", package = package), package)
  tools:::fetchRdDB(rdb_path, file)
}

pkg_topics_index <- function(package) {
  help_path <- system.file("help", package = package)

  file_path <- file.path(help_path, "AnIndex")
  if (length(readLines(file_path, n = 1)) < 1) {
    return(NULL)
  }

  topics <- read.table(file_path, sep = "\t", 
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE, comment.char = "", quote = "", header = FALSE)

  names(topics) <- c("alias", "file") 
  topics[complete.cases(topics), ]
}
```



```{r}
#| output: asis
#| echo: false

topic <- ls("package:stats", all = FALSE)[1:6]
topic_title <- topic |> 
  purrr::map( \(function_name) {
    target <- gsub("^.+/library/(.+)/help.+$", "\\1", utils:::index.search("stats", 
                                                                  find.package()))
    doc.txt <- pkg_topic(target, function_name)  # assuming both of Hadley's functions are here

    return(doc.txt[[1]][[1]][1])
  })
  


res <- purrr::map2_chr(topic, topic_title, \(topic, topic_title) {
    knitr::knit_child(text = c(
      "# `r topic_title`",
      "", 
      "```{r}",
      "#| echo: false",
      "#| class-output: r",
      "example(topic, package = 'stats', character.only = TRUE, type = 'html')",
      "```",
      "",
      ""
    ), envir = environment(), quiet = TRUE)
  })

cat(res, sep = '\n')
```
````

[image]

Comment: Great Julian. Thanks for very useful answer. Would appreciate it if you guide also how to add section numbers.

Comment: you can add section numbers using the `number-sections: true` argument in the yaml header, see [here](https://quarto.org/docs/output-formats/html-basics.html#section-numbering).

Comment: Great Julian. Thanks for very useful answer. It gives a very close result to expected output. For example, for `acf` I want to add topic title `Auto- and Cross- Covariance and -Correlation Function Estimation`.

Comment: Ah now I get it, I made an edit.

Comment: It works like a charm for `stats` package. However, it throws error for `meta` package. Please can you give it a try.

Comment: Please also retain the original answer for completeness. The new & accepted answer do not work for some packages.

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: Getting the following error with `meta` `R` package: `Error in `purrr::map()`:i In index: 1.Caused by error in `file()`:! cannot open the connectionError in vctrs_vec_compat(.y, .purrr_user_env): object 'topic_title' not foundError in cat(res, sep = "\n"): object 'res' not found1`,

Comment: Please @Julian add original answer. For me the latest version don't work for `meta` package but the old one was working. Thanks

Comment: I am on vacation for next two weeks, will correct it afterwards!